# Using dynamic fileName in camel file route

Tags: file, routes, apache-camel

I have a problem reading different fileName from Camel file component.

```
from("file:/in?fileName={{property.name}}")
    .to(file:/out)
```

I used `fileName={{property.name}}` from application.yml, but I need to use it from String.

Is there any way to use it like:

```
String name = "blabla.xml";

from("file:/in?fileName=${name}")
    .to(file:/out)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Camel don't support it. String concatenation can solve your problem:

```
from("file:/in?fileName="+name)
```

or you can set a property and then read it:

```
String name="name";
from("direct:start")
    .setProperty("name",constant(name))
    .to("file:/in?fileName=${exchangeProperty.name}");
```